# how to throttle in camel context

Tags: java, apache-camel, throttling

I am using Apache camel and jboss fuse, I have created a sample route blue print listed below in, i have sucessfully handling exceptions in all my routes now the problem is i can not find any example of throttling in routes as i have defined. in apache camel documentation, they have given simple DSL throttling and in stackoverflow i have found rabbitMq [throttling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904114/throttling-in-camel) which is not my case. how to throttle routes like this in apache camel

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
        xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
        xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd        http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">
        <cxf:rsServer address="/testservice" id="testserver" serviceClass="com.company.HelloBean">
        <camelContext id="testContext" trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
            <route id="testRoute" >
              <throttle timePeriodMillis="10000">
                <constant>3</constant>
                <from id="_from1" uri="cxfrs:bean:testserver"/>
                    <bean beanType="com.company.HelloBean"
                        id="_bean1" method="hello"/>
              </throttle>
            </route>
        </camelContext>
    </blueprint>
```

this give error when in deploy application in jboss fuse. that can not find service

Comment: you don't throttle the bean. You throttle the route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hy, all you need is you are currently defining your from endpoint in throttle tag which is wrong you need to define the throttling tag only in TO tag like this

```
  <throttle id="_throttle1" rejectExecution="true" timePeriodMillis="10000">
                <constant>1</constant>
                <bean beanType="com.company.HelloBean"
                    id="_bean1" method="hello"/>
            </throttle>
```

when requests come to an end point from, you will throttle while requests are going TO another end point you are using beans so, you can do something like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
    xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd        http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">
    <cxf:rsServer address="/testservice" id="testserver" serviceClass="com.evampsaanga.gethomepage.GetHomePageDataLand">
        <cxf:providers>
            <bean class="com.evampsaanga.restresponses.ExceptionHandler" id="securityException"/>
        </cxf:providers>
    </cxf:rsServer>
<!--     <bean class="com.saanga.servicetest.THR" id="myPolicy"/> -->
    <camelContext id="testContext" trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route id="testRoute" >
            <from id="_from1" uri="cxfrs:bean:testserver"/>
            <log id="_log1" message="header : ${headers}"/>
            <setHeader headerName="headerbalance" id="_setHeader1">
                <simple>${headers}</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <setBody id="_setBody1">
                <simple>${body}</simple>
            </setBody>
            <throttle id="_throttle1" rejectExecution="true" timePeriodMillis="10000">
                <constant>1</constant>
                <bean beanType="com.evampsaanga.gethomepage.GetHomePageDataLand"
                    id="_bean1" method="Get"/>
            </throttle>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```